# Is it possible to load models

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-6, prism

I am building a desktop application which uses prism framework. The solution contains 4 applications.

1. Core
2. ModuleA
3. ModuleB
4. Database

**1. I have two Models in Core Application:**

```
User
   Id
   Username
   CreatedAt

Activity
  Id
  Reason
  CreatedAt
```

**2. I have installed the EF6 Framework via Nugets in Database Application**

**3. I am just calling these 2 methods to create the tables**

```
Add-Migration

update-database
```

**4. I have another Modules (*ModuleA* and *ModuleB*) and those modules contains another Models, which I want to add to the database.**

```
ModuleA

Ticket
   Id
   Value
   Price
   CreatedAt

ModuleB

Voucheer
   Id
   Value
   Price
   CreatedAt
```

Now my Question is:

1. Is it possible to generate those tables on Module registration progress in Prism?
2. Or how can I create the tables, which are in another Modules without running add-migration and update-database commands via CLI ?

Comment: Migrations are just generated code, you _could_ create all that by hand...

Answer (score 0):

i can remove the need to use update-database but you will still need to generate the migration(s).  In the configuration.cs add

AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;

then where you want to update/add tables

```
        try
        {
            using (ConnectContext db = new ConnectContext())
            {
                Database.SetInitializer(
                 new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ConnectContext, Configuration ());
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
```

this will update your database to the latest migration automatically